# Symfony Class 'PDO' not found

Tags: php, symfony, pdo

I just uploaded my symfony project on an online server but it gives me this error:

[image: Error picture]

First I thought it's a problem of `pdo_mysql` extension that I should install but I found that is already installed on the server:

[image: See this picture]

What should I do?

**EDIT :**

```
public static function getConnection(
            array $params,
            Configuration $config = null,
            EventManager $eventManager = null)
    {
        // create default config and event manager, if not set
        if ( ! $config) {
            $config = new Configuration();
        }
        if ( ! $eventManager) {
            $eventManager = new EventManager();
        }

        $params = self::parseDatabaseUrl($params);

        // check for existing pdo object
        if (isset($params['pdo']) && ! $params['pdo'] instanceof \PDO) {
            throw DBALException::invalidPdoInstance();
        } elseif (isset($params['pdo'])) {
            $params['pdo']->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $params['driver'] = 'pdo_' . $params['pdo']->getAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME);
        } else {
            self::_checkParams($params);
        }
        if (isset($params['driverClass'])) {
            $className = $params['driverClass'];
        } else {
            $className = self::$_driverMap[$params['driver']];
        }

        $driver = new $className();

        $wrapperClass = 'Doctrine\DBAL\Connection';
        if (isset($params['wrapperClass'])) {
            if (is_subclass_of($params['wrapperClass'], $wrapperClass)) {
               $wrapperClass = $params['wrapperClass'];
            } else {
                throw DBALException::invalidWrapperClass($params['wrapperClass']);
            }
        }
//line 173
        return new $wrapperClass($params, $driver, $config, $eventManager);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know, what's the panel on the screen, but maybe these extensions are installed but not enabled? Look into the php.ini and check if appropriate entries are there and are uncommented.

Comment: i can't access to php.ini

Comment: Show `DriverManager` line 173 (or whole function), Mybe they are using `PDO` instead of `\PDO` class

Comment: @BogdanKuštan i've edited my question , please take a look and bye the way they are using \PDO

Answer (score 0):

You can display your server configuration to check if PDO extension is enabled or not with this function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: There is an error when accessing to this url. Have you create a new php file with "<?php phpinfo ?> and upload it to your server ? Then access to this file to see all the configuration